# How to use glossaries-package without need to print out the Glossary

Tags: beamer, glossaries

I know that it doesn't make much sense to create a glossary and then not want to use it. I print the glossary in my main document. But now I have a presentation with beamer slides, where I just copy equations from the main document. In the equations, most variables are glossary entries. But it makes no sense for me to print a glossary in my presentation. Then I get all those warnings that an entry has been referenced but does not exist, which is very annoying. Is there any way to get around this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{bp}{%type=symbols, In the original there are 2 different types of glossaries
name={\ensuremath{BP}},sort=bp,description={Basispreis einer Option}}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\frame{\gls{bp} has to give the output \ensuremath{BP}.}

%\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warnings are coming from the hyperlinks that are being created to targets that are not created.  So put this in the preamble:

```
\glsdisablehyper
```

You still get these warnings.

> ```
> Package glossaries Warning: \makeglossaries hasn't been used,
> the glossaries will not be updated.
>
> Package glossaries Warning: No \printglossary or \printglossaries
> found. This document will not have a glossary.
> ```

So just silence them with this option:

```
\usepackage[nowarn]{glossaries}
```

I think that covers it!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't work. I need the output to be `Test`. `T` is only the identifier. Actually my glossary entries are a little more complicated than in my example, I will add that as it does seem to matter.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstading—I actually haven't used the package before so I wasn't sure of the syntax.  I've edited.

Comment: The option `nowarn` will not only disable this warning but all warnings. This is not a good solution.

Comment: @fab: OP wants to not have a glossary at all, so it seems OK for this use case. I skimmed the documentation and didn't find an option to suppress this particular warning. I suppose it could be hacked together. But why? I always figured warnings were harmless.